# How to calculate coefficients for cubic least squares regression utilizing equations for summation of x- and y- data points only.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, least-squares, linear-regression, summation-method

For quadratic least squares statistical regression equations, the following is utilized for the calculation of coefficients $(a,b,c)$:

$a = \cfrac{∑(x^2y) * ∑(xx)-∑(xy) * ∑(xx^2)}{∑(xx) * ∑(x^2x^2)-∑(xx^2)^2}$

$b = \cfrac{ ∑(xy) * ∑(x^2x^2) - ∑(x^2y) * ∑(xx^2)}{∑(xx) * ∑(x^2x^2)- ∑(xx^2)^2}$

$c = \text{mean}(y) - b * \text{mean}(x) - a * \text{mean}(x^2)$

where,

$∑(xx) = ∑(x^2) - \cfrac{∑(x)^2}k$

$∑(xy) = ∑(xy) - \cfrac{∑(x)*∑(y)}k$

$∑(xx^2) = ∑(x^3) - \cfrac{∑(x)*∑(x^2)}k$

$∑(x^2y) = ∑(x^2y) - \cfrac{∑(x^2)*∑(y)}k$

$∑(x^2x^2) = ∑(x^4) - \cfrac{∑(x^2)^2}k$

Can anyone help me identify this same method for finding the coefficients $(a,b,c,d)$ with regard to cubic regression statistical equations?

Like this:

$a = ???$

$b = ???$

$c = ???$

$d = \text{mean}(y) - c * \text{mean}(x) - b * \text{mean}(x^2) - a * \text{mean}(x^3)$

where, the same identities as above, but possibly including $∑(x^3y)$, $∑(x^2x^3)$ and $∑(x^3x^3)$?

Comment: You should search for general linear least squares.  Section 15.4 of [Numerical Recipes](http://numerical.recipes/book/book.html) has a discussion, as will any numerical analysis text.  You are looking for the solution by the normal equations.

Comment: Could the formatting be improved? It is difficult to see the actual equations.

Comment: Thanks, Ross.  The Numerical Recipes didn't have anything in this specific format.

Comment: Alex, not sure I can improve but I will share my source for the quadratic model.  My reference is from a government publication found at Arizona's Dept. of Health Services site titled 'Quadratic Least Square Regression'...here is the link:  https://www.azdhs.gov/documents/preparedness/state-laboratory/lab-licensure-certification/technical-resources/calibration-training/12-quadratic-least-squares-regression-calib.pdf